# Start loading page in express/nodejs app without waiting for async function

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How can I start loading a page without having to wait for a async function (that takes ~3 seconds to complete)?

I have a Node app that uses Express and EJS as my view engine. I want to be able to start rendering the template called "send-money" (see below) without having to wait for "result" to return.

This is what my looks like (with some simplifications):

```
router.get("/sweden/poland/sek/pln/3000", async (req, res) => {

    const result = await findCheapestProvider('Sweden','Poland','SEK','PLN',3000) //takes ~3 seconds to return;

    res.render("send-money", result)
});
```

The issue can be seen live via this URL (it's in Swedish, so let your browswer's "translate to English" functionality be your friend): https://www.transferhero.se/skicka-pengar/sverige/polen/sek/pln/3000

I'm new to programminng, but I'm trying to learn through this side-project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the current implementation of the route, I can't think of a way to achieve what you are after. The view engine must have the 'result' to render and send the html to the browser.
One solution is to use an ajax call from the served html page to get the data and display it. So there will be two routes, one to just serve the html page(with the url params) and another one where the html page can get the data from.
The page will run the ajax function on page load and retrieve the data.